# Make certain pages uneditable by editors?

Tags: admin, users, user-roles

My Wordpress page has a few editors. They need this permission because they need to be allowed to change the posts/pages of others. However there two pages I want only me, the administrator to be able to edit.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I think it's also possible to use the `user_has_cap` filter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the `map_meta_cap` filter:

```
/**
 * Uneditable posts/pages for editors
 */
add_filter( 'map_meta_cap', function ( $caps, $cap, $user_id, $args )  
{
    // Edit to your needs:
    $post_ids = [123, 234, 345, 456]; // Uneditable posts   
    $role     = 'editor';             // Uneditable by this user role

    // Make given posts uneditable for the above user role:
    if (
            'edit_post' === $cap
         && isset( $args[0] )
         && in_array( $args[0], $post_ids ) 
         && current_user_can( $role )
    )
        $caps[] = 'do_not_allow';

    return $caps;

}, 10, 4 );
```

to make certain pages/posts uneditable by editors.